# Error response from daemon: chtimes /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-$: invalid argument

Tags: jenkins, docker, centos

i have docker container running on Centos 6, here is docker info:

```
Containers: 14
Images: 115
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-1568490-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem: 
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 4.381 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 7.429 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 7.205 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: false
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.4.1-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.856 GiB
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

i want to `docker commit` and `docker save` the container, i can commit it but when i try to save it, it fails:

```
Error response from daemon: chtimes /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-$: invalid argument
```

there is no timestamp for creation in config.json of the container and i read in github that is the problem but after i add to config.json it doesn't change, what should i do?
the container is jenkins cli and i have this problem with all of containers.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your docker version can resolve your problem.